# How to fix an error in SQL query on data sorting?

Tags: sql, wordpress, pivot

**I used this code to sort it:**

```
SELECT
    submit_time,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-name',     field_value, NULL)) AS Requestor,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-email',    field_value, NULL)) AS Email,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'location',      field_value, NULL)) AS Company_Name,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'telephone',      field_value, NULL)) AS Telephone,
    MAX(IF(field_name = 'your-browser',      field_value, NULL)) AS City
FROM
    wpv4_contactic_submits
GROUP BY
    submit_time
```

The data is generated correctly, but now I can't edit it. It gives out an error: 
 "Error! There was an error trying to update the row! Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Comment: How are you trying to edit it? Keep in mind you will never be able to write to computed fields (all fields but the first in your selection are computed).

Comment: @robinsax Maybe there is another option to implement this? I use a plugin to generate a table. There is an option to edit records on the front-end.